# Skipping undefined elements from an API call

Tags: javascript, api, for-loop

I am gathering data from an API to show the Pokemon typing. Some Pokemon have one type, while others have two.

The variables to gather the typing data are as such.

```
function createPokemonCard(pokemon) {
const type = pokemon.types[0].type.name;
const second_type = pokemon.types[1].type.name;
...}
```

And then I call them via InnerHTML in the same function with the following code.

```
<small class="type"><span>${type}/${second_type}</span></small>
```

Predictably, when it hits undefined for a Pokemon, it breaks and doesn't display the card. However I am not sure how to get it to not print the second type when it's undefined.

I thought about doing an if statement, but what should I call if there is an undefined variable?

```
function undefined {
if(second_type === 'undefined') {
???
}}
```

Or would a for loop work better? I am not sure how to get it to bypass the undefined and print nothing.

Comment: please don't define undefined :)

Comment: are you using react or any other framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const second_type = pokemon.types[1] ? pokemon.types[1].type.name: undefined;
`<small class="type"><span>${type}${second_type!=undefined ? `/${second_type}`: ''}</span></small>`
```

The `?` `:` syntax is a ternary operator ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator))

It's a less verbose way of writing out the following:

```js
if (second_type!=undefined) { // check if second_type is not undefined
  return `/${second_type}` // if it's not return / and the second type
} else { //otherwise
  return '' // return an empty string
}
```

Comment: The OP still wants it to print something even if the second type is undefined. They just don't want it to have the /second_type part

Comment: @nthnchu we can simply add it after `:`

Comment: "Predictably, when it hits undefined for a Pokemon, it breaks and doesn't display the card. However I am not sure how to get it to not print the second type when it's undefined." From my understanding that means that they still want type to show.

Comment: I also want to point out that `<small class="type"><span>${type}/${second_type}</span></small>` is valid jsx, but from the question they are using innerHTML, so it should be a template string: `\`<small class="type"><span>${type}/${second_type}</span></small>\`` surrounded with the "`"

Comment: we can use innerHTML in react also

Comment: Doesn't sound like the OP is using react though. (not tagged react). for react you'd also end up using `{}` instead of `${}`. `${}` is used for template strings (`\`` `\``)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224283/discussion-between-nthnchu-and-abishek-kumar).

Comment: This solution didn't work, it results in the same error. It says cannot find 'type' for undefined.

Comment: @SJK the error is in `const second_type = pokemon.types[1].type.name;`

Comment: What's the error? It shows the secondary type for the first few Pokemon, but throws up an error when it gets to the next one because it only has one type.

Here is a CodePen to see all my code if that highlights anything: https://codepen.io/ForkCode/pen/xxOyxXe

Comment: `const second_type = pokemon.types[1] ? pokemon.types[1].type.name: undefined;` add this

Comment: Ah I see, I needed to change that variable. Thank you for your help, it was a very cleans olution.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to display the trailing / when `second_type` is not defined one way to go could be

```js
const type = pokemon.types.map(({ type }) => type.name).join("/")
```

and then

```html
<small class="type"><span>${type}</span></small>
```